# How do I use a DataSnapshot object in a helper class?

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

I have a class I intend to use to retrieve entries from my Firebase Database. Methods in there include e.g. `getAllProducts() -> [Product]` as well as `getProductsByCategory(category:) -> [Product]`.

Within those methods I call the `observeSingleEvent()` method from Firebase to get a snapshot at a certain path – which works allright.

Now, so that I not have to repeat myself when creating my product object within one of the above mentioned methods I do something like this:

```
class FirebaseFactory {
self.ref.child("products").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
    var products = [Product]()
    for product in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
        let productToAdd = self.createProduct(product)   
    }
}
```

The helper class `createProduct()` looks like this:

```
func createProduct(productSnapshot: DataSnapshot) -> Product? {
        let identifier = productSnapshot.key
        if let ean = productSnapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "ean").value as? Int,
            let name = productSnapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "name").value as? String,
            let category = productSnapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "category").value as? String,
            let productCategory = Category(rawValue: category){
            let product = Product(identifier: identifier, category: productCategory, ean: ean, name: name)
            return product
        }
        return nil
    }
```

Now, even though the product object from the `for`-Loop is of the type `DataSnapshot` and my helper function expects exactly that as a parameter, Xcode shows me the failure

`'DataSnapshot' is not convertible to 'FirebaseFactory'`,

where `FirebaseFactory` is my custom class where all those methods are located in...

An overview of the class is here (with some more methods omitted):

```
class FirebaseFactory {
  /// Captures all available products in an array
  func getAvailableProducts(completion: @escaping ([Product]) -> Void) {
    self.ref.child("products").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
      var products = [Product]()
      for product in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
        let productToAdd = self.createProduct(product)
        products.append(productToAdd)
      }
    }
    completion(products)
  }

  /// Helper function to create a product from the Firebase Node
  func createProduct(productSnapshot: DataSnapshot) -> Product? {
    let identifier = productSnapshot.key
    if let ean = productSnapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "ean").value as? Int,
      let name = productSnapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "name").value as? String,
      let category = productSnapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "category").value as? String,
      let productCategory = Category(rawValue: category){
        let product = Product(identifier: identifier, category: productCategory, ean: ean, name: name)
        return product
    }
    return nil
  }
}
```

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: The code you shared doesn't declare or use `FirebaseFactory` anywhere. Are you sure this error message comes from the code you shared?

Comment: I added an overview of said class, hope that clarifies. Seems as though I still can't wrap my head around escaping closures and concurrency...